# Scala Option: isDefined vs map based approach

Tags: scala

I have a piece of code implemented in 2 ways:

```
val c = if(x.y.isDefined){
   methodA(....)
} else {
   method(....)
}
c
```

And this:

```
val c = x.y.
     map(methodA(....))
    .orElse(Some(mehodB(....))
    .getOrElse("")
c
```

x.y is an Option and methodA, methodB return String values.

Which of these approaches is more preferred in Scala? Personally I find first one to be more  easy to understand, but my more scala proficient colleague prefers second one.

Comment: Your coworker doesn't know the Scala standard library as well as he thinks he does. `.map.orElse.getOrElse` is just a really unnecessarily elaborate way to call [`fold`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/3.0.2/scala/Option.html#fold-fffff805), which is far shorter than that chained-method nonsense he suggests. Go with `fold` or the `if`, but *please* don't do whatever that other option is.

Comment: If in the first case you have something like `x.y.get()` hiding inside `....`, I strongly suggest _not_ using option 1; but pattern matching as in Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz's answer (fold will work too).

Answer (score 3):

use the `if` or something based on pattern match (by the way, no need for assigning to c if you return the expression)

```
x.y match {
   case Some(_) => methodA()
   case None => methodB()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    x.fold(methodB) { _ => methodA }
```